# How to loop through the agents which are batched together at any point?

Tags: anylogic

I am having a batching and un batching logic in my simulation model. I am collecting statistics on agent population which in my case is "MyAgent". But looks like it is ignoring the agents which are in Batch State. How can I get the agent's properties which are batched ?  I want to loop through Batch to get which agents are batched at any point in time.

-D[image]

Comment: Hey, do add some screenshots to clarify a bit more, pls :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the agents inside a batch, you can use `contents()`. Add a custom population for the batches (and add the new batches to it - see image below), let's say you call it `batchTypes`, then to loop through the batched agents, you write the following:

```
for( BatchType b : batchTypes) {
  for(int i = 0 ; i < b.contents().size() ; i++) {
    b.contents().get(i);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Followed all steps. Dont see agent getting added to collection.

Comment: Check the answer again, I made it clearer and got rid of the collection. There is an already embedded collection for batches in AnyLogic called `contents()`. The steps should be easier to follow now.

Comment: Make sure the batch block properties are set correctly as shown above.